# How do I use strong induction in a specific proof that involves metric spaces?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I have to prove the forward direction of the following: Prove that a metric space $X$ is not totally bounded iff $\exists \varepsilon_0$ and there exists a sequence $\{p_k\}$ in $X$, such that $d(p_j,p_k)\geq \varepsilon_0$, $\forall j\neq k$.

The definition that I have of totally bounded is: A metric space $(X,d)$ is totally bounded provided that $\forall \varepsilon \gt0$ there exists a finite set $\{p_1,p_2,...,p_k\} \subseteq X$ such that $\forall p \in X$ $\exists i \in \{1,2,...,N\}$ such that $d(p,p_i)\lt \varepsilon$.

I have already completed the converse proof and I am struggling with the forward direction. I assumed that $X$ is not totally bounded and then I negated the definition I have of totally bounded. My professor did instruct me to use strong induction to "create" a specific sequence.

I know that for strong induction I have to assume the following: For all $\{p_1,p_2,...,p_k\}$ assume that $d(p_j,p_l)\geq \varepsilon_0$ for all $j\neq l \leq k$. I then know that I have to add $p_{k+1}$ to the sequence and show that $d(p_n,p_{k+1}) \geq \varepsilon_0$ for all $n \leq k$.

I do not know how to use strong induction in this case. What do I manipulate? Intuitively it makes sense to me since every point is at a distance greater than $\varepsilon_0$ from each other, if I just add another point to that then it should also be a distance greater than $\varepsilon_0$ from all the other points.

Answer (score 1):

Since $X$ is not totally bounded, there exists a point $p_{k+1}$ s.t. $d(p_{k+1},p_n)\geq {\epsilon}_0$ for all $n\leq k$; otherwise every point is within an ${\epsilon}_0$-neighboorhood of some $p_n$, which means $X$ can be covered by finitely many ${\epsilon}_0$-neighboorhoods, contradictory to the choice of ${\epsilon}_0$. Now for $i,j\geq k$, $d(p_i,p_j) \geq {\epsilon}_0$; for $j=k+1$, $d(p_i,p_{k+1}) \geq {\epsilon}_0$. Hence the induction is complete.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is the following: it suffices to find $p_{k+1}$ that is at least at $\varepsilon_0$ distance of the points already chosen. Assume not. What does this mean? Well, if we pick *any* point $p \in X$, then $p$ cannot satisfy the former because we're assuming no such point exists. Hence $p$ is at distance less than $\varepsilon_0$ from some of the points $p_1, \dots, p_k$. But this shows that $X$ is totally bounded, which is absurd.

Comment: I don't understand this too well. Would I say something like suppose by contradiction that there exists a point $p_{k+1}$ such that $d(p_n,p_{k+1}) \lt \varepsilon_0$ for some $p_n \in X$.... But, I don't see how to continue.

Comment: Let me rephrase this, then. The inductive step consists on proving that given these $p_1, \dots, p_k$ you can add a new point $p_{k+1}$ such that they are all still far apart enough (I avoided symbols in order for you to fill the details, take this as a hint if you will). Now, equivalently we can assume that no such point exists and derive a contradiction. That means that for any point $p \in X$ we pick, we can't set $p_{k+1} := p$. This impossibility can only exist if some $p_i$ is at distance $\varepsilon_0$ or less of $p$. But this is absurd, because it says $X$ is totally bounded.